# How JQuery architechted around javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery, I don't want to just learn syntax , I want to know how it works. here is basic syntax for DOMready function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
});
```

My questions are :

1. What is $, is its Object or Function ?
2. what is function() , are we passing function ? It looks to me a nested function?
3. I want to  know the call stack for jQuery programme.

Comment: What does "I want to know the call stack for jQuery programme" mean?

Comment: You can get all your answers on  https://jquery.com/ and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/

Answer (score 1):

> 1. What is $, is its Object or Function.

Yes. :-) Functions are proper objects in JavaScript, so it's both. And jQuery makes explicit use of that fact, because you can call `$()` (as you have), and you can also use properties jQuery added to the function, like `$.ajax`.

> 2. what is function() , are we passing function ?

Exactly, yes. That code creates a function, and passes the resulting function reference into the `ready()` function; jQuery will call that function when it determines that the DOM is fully loaded ("ready").

> 3.I want to know the call stack for jQuery programme.

There is no specific one "call stack." What you may want here is: JavaScript on browsers runs in an "event loop." When something happens (the page loads, the user clicks something), JavaScript code associated with that event is run by the browser, which maintains a queue of these calls (if needed) and runs them one at a time. (By default in browsers there's only one queue [leading to the incorrect-but-common belief that JavaScript is "single threaded"]; you can create others with things called *web workers*, but that's a more advanced topic.)

Comment: Thank you, exactly a kind of answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

The $ is just a function. It is actually an alias for the function called jQuery:

You can write as

```
$( document ).ready()
```

or

```
jQuery( document ).ready()
```

You can also use the shorthand `$()` for `$( document ).ready()`